# Adding a WCF application as a folder in IIS 6.1

Tags: wcf, iis

How can i add a WCF application as a folder under IIS. Iam able to host the WCF application as a Virtual Directory. But the client requirement is to host it as a simple folder. I dont see any option to add an application as a folder in IIS. How can i achieve this?[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your client is using fuzzy terminology.  It's either an IIS vdir or an IIS App, and there's very little difference.  It's possible that the client already has a vdir set up. In that case maybe he wants you to drop the WCF code into a subfolder of that vdir. you will need to verify. If that's the case, then you have no business going into the iis manager.  Just create a subfolder in the physical directory that corresponds to his vdir, and drop your files there.